# TYPO3 tx_news: How to remove "News" from RealURL path

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have configured RealURL and tx_news in TYPO3 6.x according to the [basic setup](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/latest/Main/Administration/Realurl/Index.html) from the manual.

The generated URL for a single view is:

```
http://www.domain.com/news/detail/News/title-of-news/
```

That's quite ok - but how to remove the second, uppercase "News" from the URL, to make it look like this?:

```
http://www.domain.com/news/detail/title-of-news/
```

Comment: This question has already been answered here, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238739/typo3-tx-news-how-to-remove-news-prefix-from-realurl-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to switch from using `postVarSets` configuration (which uses a **keyword** in the URL to identify how to process the values in the URL that follow) to `fixedPostVars` configuration which is based on the **page UID**. That's its slight drawback - you have to set the page UIDs in the RealURL config which means that it can be done only by an admin.

See the *Advanced example* in the manual that you posted yourself.

Comment: But I don't have one single detail view page, but many. So I probably can't use the fixedPostVars version, right?

Comment: That's not a problem. You can have as many detail pages as you want. Basically you create one named configuration of `fixedPostVars` (see e.g. *newsDetailConfiguration* in the page you provided) and you can then assign this configuration to as many pages as you want (see pages 70 and 701 have this assigned in that example).

Comment: The original idea was to use unlimited detail pages, using the "override list view" mode. In the meantime, I have abandonned the idea as well. It's much more stable to have the good old detail view page(s) and do it with the `fixedPostVars` config